# How to convert BLOB data (ex: 136948a98e67) retrieved from DB2 into JSON format/String using java

Tags: java, json, string, db2, blob

I am able to fetch and convert BLOB to string, but special or control characters are also being displayed.

For instance This is the output -

"\u0003?\u0004\u0000\u0000\u0003BUSINFON\u0000?\u0004\u0000\u0000\u0002DATA1\u0000\u0003\u0000\u0000\u000006\u0000\u0002USER_ID\u0000\u0014\u0000\u0000\u00002022-01-01-01.01.01\u0000\u0002EMPLOYEE_NAME\u0000\u0007\u0000\u0000\u0000ABCDEF\u0000\u0002EMPLOYEE_ID\u0000\u0007\u0000\u0000\u0000ZGSET4\u0000\u0002PAYMENT\u0000\u0007\u0000\u0000\u0000METHOD\u0000\u0002VZDLR_ZGPREF_FK1\u0000\u0006\u0000\u0000\u0000INFORMATION\u0000\u0002VZBCO_SPOUSE_FK2\u0000\u0007\u0000\u0000\u0000SPOUSE\u0000\u0002ASIGNMENT_ID

Basically I am trying to retrieve/read data from a table present in DB2 mainframe the column "COLUMN_NAME" is set to data type of BLOB.

Here's my intended code snippet :

```
String q= "select  COLUMN_NAME from TABLE_TEST";
PreparedStatement pstate = null;
        PreparedStatement p = null;
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.setProperty("useJDBC4ColumnNameAndLabelSemantics", "2");
        // props.setProperty("DB2BaseDataSource.NO", "2");
        props.setProperty("user", "******");
        props.setProperty("password", "*****");
        //PreparedStatement pstate1 = null;
        ResultSet res=null;
        Connection connection = null;
        
        
        try {
         
         Class.forName(jdbcClassName);
         
         System.out.println("DB2 driver is loaded successfull \n");
         
         connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, props);

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
         } catch (SQLException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
         }finally{
         if(connection!=null){
         System.out.println("Connected successfully.\n");
         
         pstate=connection.prepareStatement(q);
         
         res = pstate.executeQuery();
         
          while(res.next()) 
         {
           String payl = res.getString("COLUMN_NAME");
           byte [] Blob; 
           Blob pay1 =  res.getBlob("COLUMN_NAME");
           InputStream in = pay1.getBinaryStream();
           Reader reader1 = new InputStreamReader(in, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
           JsonReader reader2 = new JsonReader(reader1);
           reader2.setLenient(true);
           JsonElement out =  JsonParser.parseReader(reader2);
           System.out.println(out);
           
        }
```

Comment: That's not JSON. It's binary data - full of non-printing characters

Comment: What encoding is used for the string in the BLOB? Why not a CLOB? Why not native JSON? And which platform / OS / Db2 version?

Comment: What's the text representation of this JSON document? How did you put the BLOB value into the `COLOUMN_NAME` column exactly?

Comment: The only good reason I can think of for using a blob column for JSON is if it's had some sort of 'binary-ising' processing such as compression. Has it?

Comment: No idea about the DB part, but the DBA informed that it of the type BLOB and they have used SYSTOOLS.JSON2BSON function while inserting data in mainframe DB2.

Comment: Consider using systools.BSON2JSON then.  https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2-for-zos/11?topic=sql-bson2json

Comment: Tried using systools.BSON2JSON in select statement but did not work.

Comment: `CREATE TABLE TEST_JSON (B BLOB (1K))`, `INSERT INTO TEST_JSON (B) SELECT SYSTOOLS.JSON2BSON ('{Name:"George"}') FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1`, `SELECT SYSTOOLS.BSON2JSON (B) FROM TEST_JSON`. You must work with `CLOB` data type in your application with the result of the last statement, not with `BLOB`.

Comment: *No idea about the DB part, but the DBA informed that it of the type BLOB and they have used SYSTOOLS.JSON2BSON function while inserting data in mainframe DB2.* OK so I was right. That's good and now you know what to do from the others

Answer (score 0):

Consider using BSON2JSON (docs: https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2-for-zos/11?topic=sql-bson2json)

```
String q= "select SYSTOOLS.BSON2JSON(COLUMN_NAME) from TABLE_TEST";
```